# Перебор элементов словаря (Yandex.Parktikum)

Tags: python

4 тема, 4 урок. Нам дана задача:

> Научите Анфису собирать словарь friends с нуля. Вам дано два списка:
> friends_names , имена друзей, и friends_cities — их города. Списки
> соответствуют друг другу: friends_names[0] живёт в городе
> friends_cities[0]. Напечатайте на экран сообщение "Лена живёт в городе
> <город>", используя доступ по ключу в словаре friends.

Подсказка:

> Перебрать значения одновременно в двух списках вам поможет функция
> range(0, len(friends_names)) и доступ к элементам списка по индексу:
> friends_cities[i]. Новые пары в словарь добавьте через доступ по
> ключу.

p.s нашел ответ в интернете:

```
friends_names = ['Аня', 'Коля', 'Лёша', 'Лена', 'Миша']
friends_cities = ['Владивосток', 'Красноярск', 'Москва', 'Обнинск', 'Чебоксары']

friends = {}
for i in range (len(friends_names)):
    friends[friends_names[i]] = friends_cities [i]

print ('Лена живёт в городе', friends['Лена'])
```

ВОПРОС:

Не МОГУ понять, зачем на делать это через 'Range'??
И как нам переменная [i] дала именно ЛЕНУ и ОБНИНСК?
Объясните пожалуйста!

Comment: Т.е. мы после списка сделали пустой словарь. Потом дали указание переменной, что [i] будет равна списку городов из списка имен.
Вопрос: как система знает, что переменная [i] равна friends_names/cities[3] ???

Answer (score 0):

`i` - это индекс, номер в списке. `friends_names[0]` обращается к нулевому (первому по порядку) предмету из списка, т.е. `'Аня'` и т.д.

Неужели  об индексации коллекций ещё ничего не  изучали?

Comment: Усвоил! 
Благодарю!

Answer (score 0):

Дополню ответ MBo

В какой-то момент `friends_names[i]` станет равно `"Лена"`. Тогда в словарь по ключу `"Лена"` добавится то, что лежит в `friends_cities[i]`. Так как индекс Лены в первом списке 3, то берется город с индексом 3, то есть Обнинск

Comment: Усвоил! 
Благодарю!

Comment: Выберите подходящий ответ и отметьте его как решение  галочкой слева

Answer (score 0):

Я просто оставлю это здесь:

```
friends_names = ['Аня', 'Коля', 'Лёша', 'Лена', 'Миша']
friends_cities = ['Владивосток', 'Красноярск', 'Москва', 'Обнинск', 'Чебоксары']

friends = {name: city for name, city in zip(friends_names, friends_cities)}

print ('Лена живёт в городе', friends.get('Лена'))

# Лена живёт в городе Обнинск
```